# JQuery if statement not working as expected and == stop working

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

this code is not working. Used to do it with source ==  "youtube" but suddenly == doesnt even work or return anything and when i do it like this, always only one of the ifs gets approve, either youtube either vimeo, depends which one you put first in the code. I checked the source which is passed to the function and it is good. So what is the problem? annd why did == stop working?

```
if (source = "youtube") {
    $("#videowrap article").html("<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_url+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    $("#videowrap article iframe").css({"width" : VideoWidth+"px","height" : VideoHeight+"px"});
    $("#videowrap article").css("marginLeft",MarginLeft+"px");
    $("#videowrap").fadeIn(500);
}
if (source = "vimeo") {
    $("#videowrap article").html("<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+video_url+"?badge=0' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>");
    $("#videowrap article iframe").css({"width" : VideoWidth+"px","height" : VideoHeight+"px"});
    $("#videowrap article").css("marginLeft",MarginLeft+"px");
    $("#videowrap").fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: I cant see enough of your code to know why it is not working, but you MUST use `==` to check conditions.  If not, you are setting the variable to that value, not checking the variable's value.

Comment: have you tried with `else if` with `==`?

Comment: What you are doing here is setting `source` to equal "youtube" which will return true regardless of the value of `source` before hand, you need to use == or === to compare, it the doesn't work it means that `source` doesn't equal "youtube" or "vimeo" try debugging with firebug or similar to see what it actually is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (source == "vimeo")
```

or

```
 if (source === "vimeo")
```

not

```
if (source = "vimeo")
```